# Unable to fetch data from Firebase in Android Studio but able to save it

Tags: firebase, android-studio

I am making my first app using Firebase. I am unable to fetch data from Firebase in Android Studio but I was able to upload it using login and sign up features which I created in my app.

Whenever I run the app, it does not show any error but app automatically closes after the splash screen. I am unable to resolve this error.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.blooddonationapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nav_view;

    private CircleImageView nav_profile_image;
    private TextView nav_fullname, nav_email, nav_bloodgroup, nav_type;

    private DatabaseReference userRef;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Blood Donation App");

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        nav_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        nav_profile_image = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_image);
        nav_fullname = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_fullname);
        nav_email = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_email);
        nav_bloodgroup = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_bloodgroup);
        nav_type = nav_view.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.nav_user_type);

        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()
        );

        userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){

                    String name = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                    nav_fullname.setText(name);

                    String email = snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString();
                    nav_email.setText(email);

                    String bloodgroup = snapshot.child("bloodgroup").getValue().toString();
                    nav_bloodgroup.setText(bloodgroup);

                    String type = snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString();
                    nav_type.setText(type);

                    String imageUrl = snapshot.child("profilepictureurl").getValue().toString();
                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(imageUrl).into(nav_profile_image);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.profile:
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**ProfileActivity.java**

```
package com.example.blooddonationapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView type, name, email, idNumber, phoneNumber, bloodGroup;
    private CircleImageView profileImage;
    private Button backButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Profile");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        type = findViewById(R.id.type);
        name = findViewById(R.id.name);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        idNumber = findViewById(R.id.idNumber);
        phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        bloodGroup = findViewById(R.id.bloodGroup);
        profileImage = findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
        backButton = findViewById(R.id.backButton);

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()){
                    type.setText(snapshot.child("type").getValue().toString());
                    name.setText(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    idNumber.setText(snapshot.child("idnumber").getValue().toString());
                    phoneNumber.setText(snapshot.child("phonenumber").getValue().toString());
                    bloodGroup.setText(snapshot.child("bloodgroup").getValue().toString());
                    email.setText(snapshot.child("email").getValue().toString());

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(snapshot.child("profilepictureurl").getValue().toString()).into(profileImage);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                return  true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
}
```

**Firebase**

[image]

**LogCat**

[image]

Comment: If the app closes (crashes), there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have attached the logcat image. Please see to it.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting this error? Besides that, do you want to get the data only from the logged-in user or from all users?